# What is the name for the complexity class $O(n^{1+\epsilon})$

Tags: terminology, asymptotics, landau-notation

Sometimes problems can be solved in $O(n^c)$ time for any $c > 1$, but not for $c=1$. Typically this is written as $O(n^{1 + \epsilon})$, since $\epsilon$ is understood to be some small positive constant. I want to know the terminology for describing this complexity class.

For example, I would call a $\Theta(n)$ algorithm "linear". I would call a $\Theta(n^2)$ algorithms "quadratic". I would call a $\Theta(n \cdot log^c(n))$ algorithm "[nearly linear](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/viola/classes/toc-spring11/papers/GurevichShelah89nearly.pdf)". (Note that nearly linear is better than $O(n^{1+\epsilon})$.)

What do I call algorithms that are in $O(n^{1+\epsilon})$?

Comment: Note that $\Theta(n \log n)$ is also called *linearithmic*. While I don't know about other $c$ (polylinearithmic?), that might free up "nearly" or "almost" for you.

Comment: I'm not sure there is an agreed term, but if you use either sub-quadratic, almost linear or even quasi-linear (which is sometimes used for $O(n\log n)$ as well), yet **clearly define** that you use this term for $O(n^{1+\epsilon})$, it will be just fine.

Comment: I'd call it "linear-ish".

Answer (score 1):

The term I've seen [in use](http://arxiv.org/find/all/1/all:+superlinear/0/1/0/all/0/1) is [*superlinear*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/superlinear), as in ["Are there super-linear time complexity lower bounds for any natural problem in NP?"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4953/super-linear-time-complexity-lower-bounds-for-any-natural-problem-in-np/27711)

Comment: I think super-linear in that context means $\omega(n)$, as opposed to $\Theta(n^{1+\epsilon})$ or $O(n^{1+\epsilon})$.